# Positioning images within grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get the flag icons in the header closer together (I've attached a picture of the relevant section). I've switched around CSS values, but so far no success. I'm using Bootstrap as well.

Here is the relevant code:

```css
.flag {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light mb-3">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="./images/logo/LOGO DARKGLOBE.png" height="100px" width="150px">
        </a>
        
        <ul class="navbar-nav align-items-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="./home.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle=dropdown href="#">Empresa</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Quem somos</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Missao & Valores</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Ambiente & Sustentabilidade</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Higiene, Seguranc & Saude</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Emprego & Igualdade de Oportunidades</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projectos em Curso</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="./contactos.html">Contacto</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="flag" src="./images/flags/portugal-flag-button-round-icon-256.png">
                        </a>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="flag" src="./images/flags/spain-flag-button-round-icon-256.png">
                        </a>  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="flag" src="./images/flags/france-flag-button-round-icon-256.png">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="flag" src="./images/flags/united-kingdom-flag-button-round-icon-256.png">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I'm guessing this is a fairly straightforward fix, but this is the first time I'm creating a website from scratch. The little I know about web design I've gleamed from reading here and there. Thanks in advance!

[Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwSdU.png)

Comment: You've made some row's with 2 images inside, that makes it easy to style. use flexbox(https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on nav-item. something like: display:flex; and flex-directon:row;

Comment: by "closer together" you mean aligned? or just closer?? it isn't clear

Comment: Plastic, sorry about the lack of clarity. I meant that I would like the left-hand flag icons to be closer to the right-hand.

Comment: Thank you Ramon. That helped.